# how to numeric sort in datagridview

Tags: c#, delegates, eventhandler

I am using a DataGridView.

ValueType is Object. So, it orders it starting from the first number.

But i want to sort by numeric.

Next is my Code.

```
public event DataGridViewSortCompareEventHandler OnSortCompare;
DataGridView Grid; 
Grid.ColumnHeaderMouseClick += Grid_ColumnHeaderMouseClick;
Grid.OnSortCompare += new DataGridViewSortCompareEventHandler(Grid_SortCompare);

void Grid_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender,    DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    OnSortCompare(sender, ***?***); 
}

void Grid_SortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
{
   int a = int.Parse(e.CellValue1.ToString());
   int b = int.Parse(e.CellValue2.ToString());
   e.SortResult = a.CompareTo(b);
   e.Handled = true;
}
```

But I don't know how i can pass 'e'(DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e).

it is  '*** ? ***' in my code.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort your grid like the following.

```
Grid.Sort(Grid.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Descending);
```

Just be aware the `ValueType` of the column must be set to the correct type or the sorting won't work correctly.

```
Grid.Columns[0].ValueType = typeof(int);
```

Comment: ValueType is Object.. I can't change the valueType..How  can i do?

Comment: @SuYeonChoi I've aded a sample in my updated answer.